# How to pass a callback parameter to my service class with IServiceCollection in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

First of all, I want to apologize for my bad English cause I'm a Chinese. And I will try my best to describe my question now. If you can read this patiently and give me some recommendations it would be appreciated.

I am going to develop a Web application with `Microsoft.AspNetCore`. There is a sub-project with a service class named `MyService` and a `ServiceCollectionExtensions` used to add `MyService` to `WebHostBuilder`.

```
public class MyService: IMyService
{
    public MyService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, Func<RequestContext> callBack = null)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _callBack = callBack;
    }
}

public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyService(this IServiceCollection services, Func<RequestContext> callBack = null)
    {
         services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

         // TODO: pass callBack function to the constructor of MyService
         return services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
    }
}
```

So my question is how can I pass the callBack parameter to the constructor of `MyService` class?

Answer (score 0):

The addScoped methods has a few overloads one of which is a factory which creates the instance of the service so you can use that overload and pass in your created factory and in the factory definition add pass the callback in your Service constructor. You will find more details here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addscoped?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddScoped_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Type_System_Func_System_IServiceProvider_System_Object__

Answer (score 0):

Write your extension method as follows:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyService(this IServiceCollection services, Func<RequestContext> callBack = null)
    {
        services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>(sp => new MyService(new HttpContextAccessor(), new Func<RequestContext>(target)));

        return services;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi TanvirArjel, Thank you for your response! And what is the target parameter of Func<RequestContext>?